# SharePoint App communcation

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, farm-solution

Currently in the development of a SharePoint farm solution for my company.

I am questioning the decision of a farm solution and I would like some input.

A summary of the custom application:

- Custom form that will read/write from/to multiple lists
- Permission trimmed based on user
- Attached documents that will be stored on a SharePoint App document library.

I feel like a SharePoint app can accomplish this except for communicating to the document library to store and grab documents for the form.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

It really looks like Microsoft is leaning away from farm solutions and towards App development but everything I've read suggests that apps are very cut off.

I have pretty much only worked on sharepoint farm solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an application that has a form, some related data and some security requirements. You could do a solution using any number of patterns. As usual, the devil is in the details.

Will this solution live in only one site or do you need the ability to provision to a number of sites?  What are your organization's procedures for dev/test/deployment? Do they follow a strict software development methodology or do they do 'development in production'? Are you planning to upgrade or move to the cloud at any point in the future? Do you have high expectations for branding, or will the default SharePoint look and feel be okay?

Given how much detail you've given us, the scope of your project could be a two-day effort for one developer, or could be something that keeps a whole team engaged for six months.

At the simplest interpretation of your requirements, it could be done via script editors and a few lines of strategic jQuery, and a bit of manual setup of your information architecture.

At the most complex, you could be in for highly customized elements everywhere, and automated provisioning process, dedicated dev and QA environments, testing cycles and the like.

Like I said, the devil's in the details.

If your organization has expertise in Farm solutions, and understands the implications of that versus the direction of the platform and your organization's plans for the future, then that's a valid approach. Similarly, if your organization has a tight timeline and cannot stomach the churning that goes along with a new project in an unknown technology, that also gives credence to Farm solutions. (I cannot believe I just said that)

If you're itching to ramp up on new patterns for development, I'd skip the provider- and SharePoint-hosted apps altogether. They have a horrible user experience, and there's almost always better, more direct ways to solve problems than those approaches. Instead I'd look into the SharePoint Framework, although I can't say I've had experience using it against on-premises SharePoint.